# He hasn't the ____________ idea of the problems involved

Tags: exam-questions

Which option fits best in the following question?

> He hasn't the ____________ idea of the problems involved.

1. weakest
2. faintest
3. most minute
4. feeblest

And what does the sentence mean? All the options seem synonym .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic expression you may be looking for is

> He hasn't the **faintest** idea of the problems involved.

Although they can be considered to be synonyms of each other, your other alternatives will sound awkward to a native ear since they are usually associated with other nouns

> **weakest** link
>   **most minute** detail
>   **feeblest** mind